# Open files with "whitespace names" from within Vim with gx

Tags: netrw, filesystem

I have a file, e.g. `~/abc def.mp3` that I want to open from within a Vim buffer that already contains these lines.

If there were no whitespaces in the filename, I could simply open the file with the standard application for that file type by having the cursor on its name somewhere and pressing `gx`. How could I make this work with a file that includes whitespaces?

I already tried to visually select it and press `gx` (with or withouth including a `\` before the whitespace, surrounding double quotes etc.) but can't figure it out.

Comment: Visual selection + `gx` works for me (a line containing `~/foo bar.txt`, with visual selection from `~` to the final `t`, as opposed to a selection to the end of line, pressing `gx` opens gvim with the appropriate file).

Comment: @muru: Hm, `gx` does not work for me when I am in visual mode, I just tried your example with a text file. `gf` on the other hand does work. When I press `gx` in visual mode, I get the usual error sound GNOME produces when an operation fails. Any ideas what might cause this behaviour? Perhaps I have to go through my list of plugins...

Comment: If you cant open filename with spaces, You can escape spaces in filename by typing \ before each space

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround until `gx` is fixed.

I created a map key that will do the job. The trick was to surround the path with `"` [ double quotes ]

**Disclaimer :** This uses `open` command that works only on a Mac

There are some gotchas that you need to keep in mind while using this

The assumptions are that

1. There is only one file path on a given line and
2. There is no other text after the file path on that line
3. I have only assumed *nix like paths

**Scenario 1 : File name starting after a hypen**

Ex : `- /path/ to /file with spaces.pdf`

I had the above line in my markdown file. So I created a specific map key for this scenario

`:nnoremap <C-o> ^wy$:! open "^R""^M^M`

- The `^w` takes the cursor to the first word from the beginning of the line
- `y$` copies the rest of the line to clipboard
- `! open` : Please make sure you keep that space between `!` and `open`
- `^R"` inserts the data present in clipboard to the command mode

  - Note how the copied text is surrounded by a pair of `"`
  - This was needed to take care of the spaces in the file path

So, now with the cursor on any character of the file path, pressing `<ctrl-o>` opens me the file with the associated application

**Scenario 2 : File name starting anywhere in a line**

Ex :  `some text : /path/ to /file with spaces.pdf`

Assumption here is that :

1. All file paths are absolute and begin with a `/`
2. There is no `/` in the text before the absolute path
3. There is only one `.` in the file name

`:nnoremap <C-p> ^f/vf.ey:! open "^R""^M^M`

- `f/` moves the cursor to the first `/` on the line
- `f.` moves the cursor to the first `.` within the absolute file path
- `e` takes the cursor to the end of file path
- `y` copies the text that is blocked by the `v` : visual mode

The rest is same as Scenario 1.

So, now with the cursor on any character of the file path, pressing `<ctrl-p>` opens me the file with the associated application

Ofcourse, instead of using `<ctrl-o>` and `<ctrl-p>`, you can specify map keys that suit you.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You may want to consider using `nnoremap`

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble Updated the answer with your suggestion.